# djangoでwebサーバを停止、再起動する方法を知りたい

Tags: python, python3, django

下記のページを参考にdjangoでwebサーバーを実行しました。
https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbooks.io/workshop_tutorialjp/django_installation/
https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbooks.io/workshop_tutorialjp/django_start_project/

しかし、一度サーバーを停止して再び実行するときの方法がいまいちわかりません。
（URL2つめの最後に書いてあります）
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>で停止します。Djangoを起動したら、標準出力に停止方法が出力されますよね。`Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`って。

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 30, 2018 - 18:09:26
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: そこまではわかります。一度停止して再び実行する時にどうしたらいいかわからないです。

Comment: 自分で考えてみたんですけど、まずは仮想環境の使用。次にデータベースの作成。最後にサーバーを動かす。って流れであってますか？

Comment: 停止したら、`python manage.py runserver`で再び起動できますが、何が分からないのでしょう？

Comment: 仮想環境は必要に応じて使用すればいいですが、任意です。Modelクラスやメッセージファイルを修正したら、それを反映させるコマンドを実行しないと変更が反映されませんが、それ以外では開発中も再起動の必要性は特にないはずです。

Comment: 再起動できました。ありがとうございます。